# Read pdf in perl CAM::PDF

Tags: perl

I want to install perl module CAM::PDF for Linux. Can somebody please suggest that how can this be done? I was unable to find any place where I could download this module from.

Answer (score 1):

> I was unable to find any place where I could download this module from

HOW???

This module available on CPAN.

Try `cpanp install CAM-PDF`

Comment: I was doing it on Linux. Sorry I am not so sure how to do this? Is there no way to yum install. As my linux installation does not seem to have cpanp

Comment: @user1994531, installation perl module with CPAN is a good way. If you don't have a "cpanp" command you may try to use "cpan CAM::PDF".

Comment: I tried cpan and it says that command is not found.